# MySQLi optional WHERE clause depending on if condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, where-clause

While trying to optimize some code I came across another question.. Using usergroups and permissions, I sometimes need to add a `WHERE` clause when a user has limited permissions.. I could put the whole query inside the `if {...}`, but that would mean to repeat the same code except one line.. So I changed the code that only the statement is built depending on the if condition, instead of repeating the whole part (statement, prepare, execute, fetch..):

```
if (in_array('Edit own', $_SESSION['user_r']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT
                `news_id`
            FROM
                `news`
            WHERE
                `news_user_id` = "' .$_SESSION['user_id']. '"';
}
else if (in_array('Edit all', $_SESSION['user_r']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT
                `news_id`
            FROM
                `news`';
}
```

I know it's also possible to "split" the statement, using the if condition within the statement like this :

```
$sql = 'SELECT
            `news_id`
        FROM
            `news`';

if (in_array('Edit own', $_SESSION['user_r']))
{
     $sql .= ' WHERE
                 `news_user_id` = "' .$_SESSION['user_id']. '"';
}
```

At first glance the 2. example could be "better" since there is no repeat and the code is short, but when it comes to prepared statements and bind_param(), the first example might be better, because I can add

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $what, $ever);
```

directly after the statement inside the `if {...}` ... and somehow it seems more secure to me...

So which solution should I prefer?

Comment: FWIW, PDO lets you do `$stmt->execute($params_array)`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php ... but it's probably not worth switching over just for that.

Comment: @EthanB I agree, switching to PDO just for that could be too much, but maybe I'll consider learning PDO some day.. but I'd still have to use `if {...}` to check whether I need the WHERE clause or not, right?

Comment: Yes, this is very possible: http://pastebin.com/aD3HsWAA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since there is no other answer, I want to share my "solution":

```
if (in_array('Edit own', $_SESSION['user_r']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT
                `news_id`
            FROM
                `news`
            WHERE
                `news_user_id` = ?';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['user_id']);

}
else if (in_array('Edit all', $_SESSION['user_r']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT
                `news_id`
            FROM
                `news`';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($news_id);
...
```

As already mentioned in my question, I'm using the if statement to build the whole statement now. That way, I can use bind_param inside the if statement (if needed), but don't need to repeat the execute/fetch part.